# nginx+php5-fpm .php Pages not reflecting changes

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I'm very experienced with `Apache`, but I wanted to make the switch to `Nginx` to try and gain experience with a very popular piece of software.  Unfortunately I have not gotten very far and this problem is driving me crazy.

After putting up a test page (just a simple):    echo "This is Nginx";

I decompressed my `.tar.gz` file and loaded all the web files into the directory - I check the permissions too, btw.  Unfortunately all I can see is still "This is Nginx"

Thus far I have:

- Restarted `Nginx`
- Restarted `php5-fpm` (yes, I know there are several ways for different systems, I tried them all)
- Made sure the file permissions are correct
- Reviewd my config files and server block (see below) and,
- Turned off the sendfile option in `nginx.conf`

My server block looks as follows:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name xxx;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

## Default location
location / {
    root   /srv/www;
    index  index.php;
}

## Images and static content is treated different
location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml)$ {
  access_log        off;
  expires           30d;
  root /srv/www;
}

## Parse all .php file in the /var/www directory
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return 404;
    }
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

## Disable viewing .htaccess & .htpassword
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
}
}
```

My `nginx.conf` file is the same as the default, less the SendFile change pointed out above.  Any help someone can offer would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to declare `root` within your `server` block. You only have it repeated in some `location` blocks. This is one of the [most common nginx misconfigurations](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/). Move them out to the `server` block.

Comment: Once again (I'm pretty sure you've answered my questions before) thank you Michael Hampton.  This problem was driving me insane, but like I figured it turned out to be an easy fix.  Much appreciated.